# Angular 2 Observable JWT Header issue

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

I'm having a weird problem. I need to have a successful login then save the JWT, followed by which I need to make another HTTP request with a new Header, which includes the JWT as Authorization to get the user details. Unfortunately, with my second HTTP request, I'm missing the JWT. Any help would be appreciated.

Following are my codes

API service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import { AppState } from './state.service';

@Injectable()
export class ApiService {
  token: string = this._appState.get('_token');

  headers: Headers = new Headers({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Authorization': this.token ? this.token : null
  });

  api_url: string = '/';

  constructor(private http: Http, public _appState: AppState) {}

  private getJson(response: Response) {
    return response.json();
  }

  private checkForError(response: Response): Response {
    if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
      return response;
    } else {
      let error = new Error(response.statusText);
      error['response'] = response;
      console.error(error);
      throw error;
    }
  }

  getall(path: string): Observable<any> {
    console.log('from api', this.token);
    return this.http.get(`${this.api_url}${path}`, { headers: this.headers })
    .map(this.checkForError)
    .catch(err => Observable.throw(err))
    .map(this.getJson);
  }

  get(path: string, query: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.api_url}${path}/${query}`, { headers: this.headers })
    .map(this.checkForError)
    .catch(err => Observable.throw(err))
    .map(this.getJson);
  }

  post(path: string, body): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(
      `${this.api_url}${path}`,
      JSON.stringify(body),
      { headers: this.headers }
    )
    .map(this.checkForError)
    .catch(err => Observable.throw(err))
    .map(this.getJson);
  }

  put(path: string, query: string, body): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.put(
        `${this.api_url}${path}/${query}`,
        JSON.stringify(body),
        { headers: this.headers }
      )
      .map(this.checkForError)
      .catch(err => Observable.throw(err))
      .map(this.getJson);
  }

  delete(path: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.delete(
      `${this.api_url}${path}`,
      { headers: this.headers }
    )
    .map(this.checkForError)
    .catch(err => Observable.throw(err))
    .map(this.getJson);
  }
}
```

Login Component

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormValidationService } from '../formValidation';
import { CredFormService } from './credForm.service';
import { AppState, GetUserService } from '../../services';

@Component({
  selector: 'ce-cred-form',
  styles: [require('./credForm.style.scss')],
  templateUrl: './credForm.html',
  providers: [FormValidationService, CredFormService]
})

export class CredFormComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() credFormType: string;
  @Output() loggedIn = new EventEmitter();

  public credForm: FormGroup;
  public loginForm: FormGroup;
  public cred_error_message = false;
  public _token: string;

  constructor(
    private _fb: FormBuilder,
    private _validationService: FormValidationService,
    private _credFormService: CredFormService,
    public _appState: AppState,
    public _getUser: GetUserService ) {

    }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.cred_error_message = false;
    this.credForm = this._fb.group({
      name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
      email: ['', [Validators.required, this._validationService.emailValidator]],
      password: ['', [Validators.required, this._validationService.passwordValidator]],
    });
    this.loginForm = this._fb.group({
      email: ['', [Validators.required, this._validationService.emailValidator]],
      password: ['', [Validators.required]]
    });
  }

  signup() {
    this._credFormService.signup(this.credForm.value)
    .subscribe(
      res => {
        this.ngOnInit();
        this.loggedIn.emit({ _token: res.token });
      },
      err => {
        this.cred_error_message = JSON.parse(err._body).message;
      });
  }

  login() {
    this._credFormService.login(this.loginForm.value)
    .subscribe(
      res => {
        this.ngOnInit();
        // this.loggedIn.emit({ _token: res.token });
        this._token = res.token;
        localStorage.setItem('_token', this._token);
        this._appState.set('_token', this._token);
      },
      err => {
        this.cred_error_message = JSON.parse(err._body).message;
      },
      () => {


        this._getUser.getUser()
        .subscribe(
          res => console.log(res),
          err => console.log(err),
          () => console.log('get user complete')
        );
        this.loggedIn.emit({ _token: this._token });
      });
    // return this._credFormService.login(this.loginForm.value)
  }
}
```

Login Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../../services';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class CredFormService {
  path: string = 'auth/';

  constructor( private _apiService: ApiService ) {

  }

  login(body) {
    return this._apiService.post(this.path + 'login', body);
  }

  signup(body) {
    return this._apiService.post(this.path + 'signup', body);
  }
}
```

User service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from './restful.services';

@Injectable()
export class GetUserService {

  private _path: string = 'apis/user';

  constructor( private _apiService: ApiService ) { }

  getUser() {
    return this._apiService.getall(this._path);
  }

}
```

State service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

export type InternalStateType = {
  [key: string]: any
};

@Injectable()
export class AppState {
  _state: InternalStateType = { };

  constructor() {

  }

  // already return a clone of the current state
  get state() {
    return this._state = this._clone(this._state);
  }
  // never allow mutation
  set state(value) {
    throw new Error('do not mutate the `.state` directly');
  }


  get(prop?: any) {
    // use our state getter for the clone
    const state = this.state;
    return state.hasOwnProperty(prop) ? state[prop] : state;
  }

  set(prop: string, value: any) {
    // internally mutate our state
    return this._state[prop] = value;
  }


  private _clone(object: InternalStateType) {
    // simple object clone
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify( object ));
  }
}
```

JWT isn't adding up in the header on my second request.

Comment: Same problem here, have you found solution ? :)

Comment: Yes and I was wrong. It's a promise return using Rxjs. Just follow the method..